# How can I calculate the memory of an object take in iOS

Tags: ios

How can I calculate the memory an object takes in iOS?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Where is your code? How can we give a precise answer without knowing your situation?

Comment: Create a million and look in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can use the `malloc_size(object)` to get size of an object.

Dont forget `#import <malloc/malloc.h>`

ex: `NSLog(@"size of Object: %zd", malloc_size(myObject));`

The result is in byte.

Comment: Only the result is pointless if for example your object is an array with a million elements.